# Using a while loop to remove letters

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to make a program using While to remove any letters in the `String`. 
So the string would be `abcXabcXabc` and I would say `X` and it would remove it.
I.e `abcabcabc`. I have written most of the class but I am stumped on what I would put into my while loop.

```
class LineCleaner {
    private String line;
    private char remove;

    public LineCleaner(String s, char rem) {
        setCleaner(s, rem);
    }

    public void setCleaner(String s, char rem) {
        line = s;
        remove = rem
    }

    public String getCleaned() {
        String cleaned = line;
        int loc = cleaned.indexOf(remove);

        while (/*CONDITION*/) {
            // what to do here
        }
        return cleaned;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return line + " - letter to remove " + remove;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386107/java-how-to-remove-single-character-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in function for this already:

```
str = str.replace("X", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "abcXabcXabc";
System.out.println(s.replace("X", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a `String` is immutable, this plan of concatenating is inefficient. A `StringBuilder` is recommended. Then you can iterate through the original `String` and append only the chars that are not `'X'`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
    if (c != remove) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
String cleaned = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is using [Guava's Charmatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) ! No need to make your own class for that !

```
String charsToRemove = "X"; // You can remove multiple chars at the same time !
String line = "abcXabcXabc";

String cleaned = CharMatcher.anyOf(charsToRemove).removeFrom(line);
```

#### Output

> abcabcabc