# JavaFX TextField validation for integer input and also allow either K or k(for Thousand) or M or m(for Million) in last

Tags: input, javafx, textfield, restrict

I want to add validation in javafx TextField such that user should only be able to insert integer values ([0-9] and Dot ). Also user should be able to insert either B or b(for Billion) and K or k (for Thousand) and M or m( for Million). Basically it should be an amountfield. Delete and Backspace should also work.

for example :

10k should become 10,000.00 as soon as user hit k and K should not be displayed on amountfield (textfield)
Similarly 10M or 10m should convert into 10,000,000.00

adsadi342fn3 or 31233123werwer or dsad342134k should not be allowed to enter in the textfield.

I have used getKeyChar method while validating TextField in case of Swing. But I need same implementation in case of JavaFx where we don't have getKeyChar method.

I have used the following method but the problem with this is it allows user to enter any value. example : sdafewr23rf

```
private void amountEntered() {
        if (amountField != null) {
            String value;
            char[] charArray = amountField.getText().toCharArray();
            if (charArray.length > 0)
                switch (charArray[charArray.length - 1]) {
                    case 't':
                    case 'T':
                        value = multiplyValue(amountField.getText(), new BigDecimal(1000000000000.0));
                        updateAmount(value);
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                    case 'B':
                        value = multiplyValue(amountField.getText(), new BigDecimal(1000000000.0));
                        updateAmount(value);
                        break;
                    case 'm':
                    case 'M':
                        value = multiplyValue(amountField.getText(), new BigDecimal(1000000.0));
                        updateAmount(value);
                        break;
                    case 'k':
                    case 'K':
                        value = multiplyValue(amountField.getText(), new BigDecimal(1000.0));
                        updateAmount(value);
                        break;
                    case '0':
                    case '1':
                    case '2':
                    case '3':
                    case '4':
                    case '5':
                    case '6':
                    case '7':
                    case '8':
                    case '9':
                    case '.':
                    case ',':
                        updateAmount(amountField.getText());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
        }
    }

private String multiplyValue(String number, BigDecimal multValue) {
        //get rid of "," for double parsing
        BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(cleanDouble(number.substring(0, number.length() - 1)));
        value = value.multiply(multValue);
        return value.toPlainString();
    }
```

Comment: Similar (though slightly different) question: [String with numbers and letters to double javafx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093145/string-with-numbers-and-letters-to-double-javafx)

Answer (score 2):

As well as listening to changes in the text property and reverting if they are invalid, you can use a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) to veto changes to the text. Using this approach will avoid other listeners to the `textProperty` seeing the invalid value and then seeing it revert to the previous value: i.e. the `textProperty` will always contain something valid.

The `TextFormatter` takes a `UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>` which acts as a filter. The filter can return null to veto the change entirely, or can modify properties of the `Change` as needed.

Here is a fairly straightforward example, where "k" or "K" is replaced by "000", "m" or "M" by "000000", and other non-digit characters are removed:

```
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldFilteringExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        textField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
           System.out.println("Text change from "+oldValue+" to "+newValue);
        });

        UnaryOperator<Change> filter = change -> {
            if (change.isAdded()) {
                String addedText = change.getText();
                if (addedText.matches("[0-9]*")) {
                    return change ;
                }
                // remove illegal characters:
                int length = addedText.length();
                addedText = addedText.replaceAll("[^0-9kKmM]", "");
                // replace "k" and "K" with "000":
                addedText = addedText.replaceAll("[kK]", "000");
                // replace "m" and "M" with "000000":
                addedText = addedText.replaceAll("[mM]", "000000");
                change.setText(addedText);

                // modify caret position if size of text changed:
                int delta = addedText.length() - length ;
                change.setCaretPosition(change.getCaretPosition() + delta);  
                change.setAnchor(change.getAnchor() + delta);
            }
            return change ;
        };

        textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(filter));

        StackPane root = new StackPane(textField);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You could also modify the text to introduce grouping separators (e.g. 1,000,000), though the logic gets quite tricky there. You can additionally specify a `StringConverter<BigInteger>` for the text formatter, so that the formatter itself has a value of type `BigInteger` which is the result of passing the text through the supplied converter.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to changes in the [`text` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textProperty) to check for valid inputs. Personally I prefer the user being able to input any string and not preventing any edits until the user commits the edit.

The following example is for `BigInteger` (for simplicity) only and allows any number starting with non-zero and followed either only by digits or by digits that are grouped to 3 digits by seperating them with `,`. It adds the CSS class `invalid`, if the input is not valid and converts it to a string containing only digits if the user presses enter:

```
// regex for matching the input and extracting the parts
private static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([1-9](?:\\d*|\\d{0,2}(?:\\,\\d{3})*))([tbmk]?)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

// map from suffix to exponent for 10
private static final Map<Character, Byte> SUFFIX_EXPONENTS;

static {
    Map<Character, Byte> prefixes = new HashMap<>();
    prefixes.put('k', (byte) 3);
    prefixes.put('m', (byte) 6);
    prefixes.put('b', (byte) 9);
    prefixes.put('t', (byte) 12);
    SUFFIX_EXPONENTS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(prefixes);
}

private static BigInteger convert(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Matcher m = NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(s);

    if (!m.matches()) {
        return null;
    }

    String numberString = m.group(1).replace(",", "");
    String suffix = m.group(2);

    BigInteger factor = suffix.isEmpty() ? BigInteger.ONE : BigInteger.TEN.pow(SUFFIX_EXPONENTS.get(Character.toLowerCase(suffix.charAt(0))));

    return new BigInteger(numberString).multiply(factor);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.getStyleClass().add("invalid");

    // property bound to the current number in the TextField or null, if invalid
    ObjectProperty<BigInteger> numberProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    // Binding reevaluated on every change of the text property.
    // A listener could be used instead to change the text to the
    // previous value, if the new input is invalid.
    numberProperty.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> convert(tf.getText()), tf.textProperty()));

    // change styleclass, if the string becomes (in)valid input
    numberProperty.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (oldValue == null) {
            tf.getStyleClass().remove("invalid");
        } else if (newValue == null) {
            tf.getStyleClass().add("invalid");
        }
    });

    // handle user pressing enter
    tf.setOnAction(evt -> {
        BigInteger num = numberProperty.get();
        tf.setText(num == null ? null : num.toString());
    });

    Pane root = new StackPane(tf);

    Scene sc = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

    sc.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setScene(sc);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

In the stylesheet I set the background for invalid textfields to red-tone to give the user visual feedback:

```css
.text-field.invalid {
    -fx-background-color: #f55;
}
```

If you want to prevent users from inputing anything that cannot be made a valid string by apending chars, you could remove `numberProperty` and everything related to it and add a listener that reverts to the old value instead:

```
tf.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (isInvalid(newValue)) {
        tf.setText(oldValue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I created the following class to filter input on `TextField`, which also uses the `TextFormatter` introduced in JavaFX 8.

```
public class TextFieldValidator {

    private static final String CURRENCY_SYMBOL   = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getCurrencySymbol();
    private static final char   DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();

    private final Pattern       INPUT_PATTERN;

    public TextFieldValidator(@NamedArg("modus") ValidationModus modus, @NamedArg("maxCountOf") int maxCountOf) {
        this(modus.createPattern(maxCountOf));
    }

    public TextFieldValidator(@NamedArg("regex") String regex){
        this(Pattern.compile(regex));
    }

    public TextFieldValidator(Pattern pattern){ 
        INPUT_PATTERN = pattern;
    }

    public static TextFieldValidator maxFractionDigits(int maxCountOf) {
        return new TextFieldValidator(maxFractionPattern(maxCountOf));
    }

    public static TextFieldValidator maxIntegers(int maxCountOf) {
        return new TextFieldValidator(maxIntegerPattern(maxCountOf));
    }

    public static TextFieldValidator integersOnly() {
        return new TextFieldValidator(integersOnlyPattern());
    }

    public TextFormatter<Object> getFormatter() {
        return new TextFormatter<>(this::validateChange);
    }

    private Change validateChange(Change c) {
        if (validate(c.getControlNewText())) {
            return c;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean validate(String input) {
        return INPUT_PATTERN.matcher(input).matches();
    }

    private static Pattern maxFractionPattern(int maxCountOf) {
        return Pattern.compile("\\d*(\\" + DECIMAL_SEPARATOR + "\\d{0," + maxCountOf+ "})?");
    }

    private static Pattern maxCurrencyFractionPattern(int maxCountOf) {
        return Pattern.compile("^\\" + CURRENCY_SYMBOL + "?\\s?\\d*(\\" + DECIMAL_SEPARATOR + "\\d{0," + maxCountOf+ "})?\\s?\\" +
                CURRENCY_SYMBOL + "?");
    }

    private static Pattern maxIntegerPattern(int maxCountOf) {
        return Pattern.compile("\\d{0," + maxCountOf+ "}");
    }

    private static Pattern integersOnlyPattern() {
        return Pattern.compile("\\d*");
    }

    public enum ValidationModus {

        MAX_CURRENCY_FRACTION_DIGITS {
            @Override
            public Pattern createPattern(int maxCountOf) {
                return maxCurrencyFractionPattern(maxCountOf);
            }
        },

        MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS {
            @Override
            public Pattern createPattern(int maxCountOf) {
                return maxFractionPattern(maxCountOf);
            }
        },
        MAX_INTEGERS {
            @Override
            public Pattern createPattern(int maxCountOf) {
                return maxIntegerPattern(maxCountOf);
            }
        },

        INTEGERS_ONLY {
            @Override
            public Pattern createPattern(int maxCountOf) {
                return integersOnlyPattern();
            }
        };

        public abstract Pattern createPattern(int maxCountOf);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFieldValidator(ValidationModus.MAX_INTEGERS, 4).getFormatter());
```

or you can instantiate it in a fxml file, and apply it to a customTextField with the according properties.

app.fxml:

```
<fx:define>
    <TextFieldValidator fx:id="validator" modus="MAX_INTEGERS" maxCountOf="4"/>
</fx:define>

<CustomTextField validator="$validator" />
```

CustomTextField:

```
public class CustomTextField {

private TextField textField;

public CustomTextField(@NamedArg("validator") TextFieldValidator validator) {
        this();
        textField.setTextFormatter(validator.getFormatter());
    }
}
```

For your usecase you could call the TextFieldValidor constructor with the appropriate regex pattern and add the filter of James-D's answer to `validateChange(Change c)`