# How to remove a single character in a string?

Tags: java

For example:

```
String result;

String letter_a = "a";

String letter_b = "b";

String letter_c = "c";
```

We know it's easy to concatenate strings like `result = letter_a + letter_b + letter_c` .

**Currently**, the value of the `result` is "abc".

But what if I want to subtract `letter_c` to `result` like `result = result - letter_c`. Will the result be `result = "ab"`?

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386107/how-to-remove-single-character-from-a-string). You can only use StringBuilder  Class

Comment: First thing: You can not declare variable name as `final`. `final` is reserved word

Comment: @ChiragSavsani oh sorry i forgot.

Comment: @RushiMThakker I changed my question sir. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use replace on the string so it will be final.replace("c",""); reassign this to final or any other variable

Comment: I don't know whether replacing with nothing is really the same thing as string subtraction.

Comment: Well ull replace it with nothing means tht place will become place suppose ur string is abc or acb or cba or cab so applying replace on c with nthn will make u left with a and b :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it will give you a compilation error as `error: bad operand types for binary operator '-'`

Go for `substring()` and store it back in `final1` variable again.
For your case, `final1 =final1.substring(0,final1.length()-1);`