# how to remove multiple characters by their indice from a string in java?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

How can I remove multiple characters by their index from a string. I thought to use StringBuilder's deleteCharAt function. But if I delete char one by one, I will not keep track the right index.
For example :

```
String test = "0123456789"
int[] removingIndice  = int[] {2, 4, 0};
// remove character from string
// result = "1356789"
```

Comment: **1.** What have you tried ? **2.** `String` are immutable, you can't remove anything from it. **3.** See [ask]

Comment: I know string are immutable. I was thing to use StringBuilder.

Comment: Then do it... You got downvoted because you just thought to use it without trying. You already know `StringBuilder`, so what is the question/problem ?

Comment: https://ideone.com/xXZv0O

Comment: @zxue I figured out what you are trying to do.
If you delete character by character, you loose the actual index position initially assigned for deletion and initial inputs are important especially if there are multiple same characters in the string. I'm trying for a solution, will leave ideone link here if I get desired output.

Comment: Checkout this:
https://ideone.com/w8PXxg
This should answer your question :)

Comment: FYI @RahulRaj **1** read the sorted list backward. **2** You can use `Arrays.asList(removingIndex)` to get a list easier. **3**, You want to remove character at specific index, not every corresponding value. **4** See [this ideone](https://ideone.com/ZI7M16) for your logic

Comment: @AxelH Yes, I'm aware about `StringBuilder ` , just made a different way of doing.

Comment: @RahulRaj Thanks! I think that is what  I am looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear the logic is worked, cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a new string builder,
iterate on string, add elements to builder if its index not in the array

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for(int i = 0; i< test.length; i++){
    if( !ArrayUtils.contains(removingIndice, i))
    {
        sb.append(test.charAt(i));
    }
}
test = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Wrong, il you delete like charAt(2) then the char at 4 has changed

Comment: I was edit the answer @AxelH

Comment: Indeed! Didn't noticed the edit.

Comment: @AxelH better ;) but please add some explanations, full code is not very good, even it's easy to understand

Answer (score -1):

`String` is immutable in Java, so you will need to create a new String with characters at positions 0,2,4 removed. As one option, you may use `StringBuilder` for that, as answered here: [How to remove single character from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386107/how-to-remove-single-character-from-a-string)

Answer (score -2):

1. I think, you need to redesign the task:
   "new string must contains all characters except ..."
2. Now, seems weak initial data structure and the goal.