# I finish the part of finding the char at the position my homework required, but how to delete the character from a String that I found?

Tags: java

`removeNchars` takes a String, an int and a char and returns a String: The output string is the same as the input string except that the first n occurrences of the input char are removed from the string, where n represents the input integer. If there are not n occurrences of the input character, then all occurrences of the character are removed. Do not use `arrays` to solve this problem.

> HW2.removeNchars("Hello there!", 2, 'e')
>   "Hllo thre!"
>
> HW2.removeNchars("Hello there!", 10, 'e')
>   "Hllo thr!"
>
> HW2.removeNchars("Hello there!", 1, 'h')
>   "Hello tere!"

```
public class HW2{   
    public static String removeNchars(String s, int a, char b){
       StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
       for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
           if(int i=a&& s.charAr(i)==b){
           }          
       }              
    }

}
```

Comment: You can' NOT use the variable name **s** for both your method String parameter and your StringBuilder object. Change the StringBuilder object name to **sb**. You do not want to use the variable **i** as your occurance counter, as this won't work. Use a separate counter variable for this and declare it (`int hitCounter = 0;`) above your loop. `String strgChar = Character.toString(s.charAt(i)); if (s.charAt(i) == b && hitCounter < a) { hitCounter++; strgChar = ""; } sb.append(strgChar);`.

Comment: That's what my actual mistakes and the things I need to learn

Answer (score 0):

there is more than 1 way to do it.
I can see you used StringBuilder so try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13386289/9233991)

the idea is to define string builder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputString);
```

use `deleteCharAt()` to delete the char you don't want([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt%28int%29)).

and convert it back to string

```
String resultString = sb.toString();
```

good luck

Edit:

You can also create a new `StringBuilder`(exmple name output) then iterate the src string and append the chars you don't want to remove to the output string with `.append(input);`

something like this:

```
 StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
 output.append(char);
```

and return the output string after you finish iterating.

Comment: deleteCharAt() is not allowed.only allowed to use the following methods from the Java API:

class String
length
charAt
class StringBuilder
length
charAt
append
toString
class Character
any method

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using the StringBuilder class,but as you stated above i think this will help you with your homework,lets see if it works for you.

```
public static String removeNchars(String s, int a, char b){
       String str = "";
           for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                if(a > 0 && s.charAt(i) == b)
                  {
                       a--;
                  }else 
                  {
                      str += s.charAt(i);
                  }

      }
      return str;

}
```

Comment: kind of useful helps me to rethink my logic

Answer (score -1):

You can use `s.deleteCharAt();` like this:

```
public class HW2{   
    public static String removeNchars(String s, int a, char b){
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
            if(int i=a&& s.charAr(i)==b)
                s.deleteCharAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use deleteCharAt(). only You are allowed to use the following methods from the Java API:

class String
length
charAt
class StringBuilder
length
charAt
append
toString
class Character